# How to reset 'ss-multiselect-dropdown' in angular2

Tags: angular, package, angular2-forms, multi-select, ngx-bootstrap

I have used a multiselect dropdown control for my form in angular2 using this package: https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect

I want to reset this control when clicked on Reset Button of Form.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)=save()>
    <ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="myOptions" formControlName="optionsModel"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: you have done with a `reset type` button. what's your problem?

Comment: with reset button other fields got reset but not `<ss-multiselect-dropdown>`.

Comment: so you have to make it clear in your question about what you are facing, and also post what's your expected output. I'll post an answer later, check it please.

Comment: Thank you @Pengyy. Issue solved.

Comment: you are welcome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `model-driven` form, you can reset formControl's value by calling `patchValue`.

```
reset() {
  this.myForm.get("optionsModel").patchValue([]);  // here multiselect should be reset with an empty array.
}
```

**[PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/YUHY7nW9AK8dEXQHiAAi?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

In button click event you need to set the default value.

EX:

```
ngclick(): void {

        this.colours = Array<Colour>();
        this.colours.push(new Colour(-1, 'Please select'));
        this.colours.push(new Colour(1, 'Green'));
        this.colours.push(new Colour(2, 'Pink'));

        this.car = new Car();
        this.car.colour = this.colours[1];        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TS:

```
onReset() {
   this.myForm.reset({
     optionsModel: ['']
   })
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.